# discord.js V12 ,me command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Currently I'm working on a command that when you type **,me** it will show information about you.
This is my code:

```js
var member = message.guild.member(message.member);

var status = member.presence.status;

var nickName = member.nickname;
if(nickName == null || undefined) nickName = "None";

var accountCreated = moment(member.createdAt).format("LL");

var joinedGuild = moment(member.joinedAt).format("LL");

var game = member.presence.activities[0] ? member.presence.activities[0].name : "None";

var botEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`USER INFO`)
    .setDescription(`See info about ${member.username} below!`)
    .setColor(embedColor)
    .setFooter(embedFooter)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(member.displayAvatarURL({size: 4096}))
    .addFields(
        {name: "User Name", value: member.username, inline: true},
        {name: "User ID", value: member.id, inline: true},
        {name: "User Account Created", value: accountCreated, inline: true},
        {name: "\u200b", value: "\u200b"},
        {name: "User Status", value: status, inline: true},
        {name: "User Game", value: game, inline: true},
        {name: "User Nickname", value: nickName, inline: true},
        {name: "\u200b", value: "\u200b"},
        {name: "User Joined Server At", value: joinedGuild}
    );

return message.channel.send(botEmbed);
```

But, I get an error: **TypeError: member.displayAvatarURL is not a function**
And I've tried alot of things but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `member` object doesn't have a method called `displayAvatarURL`.

The good news is that the `user` object does. So simply put a `.user` in there and it will work.